# Why does this code give me an error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
import re
with open("text2.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
numbers = re.findall(r'\b\d{3}\b', content)
with open("text3.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(numbers))
```

When run, it's supposed to find all of the three digit numbers, and print them to a new text file.

When I run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zach\Desktop\test3.py", line 4, in <module>
    numbers = re.findall(r'\b\d{3}\b', content)
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.7.2\python\lib\re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `file.readlines()` returns list of string, `re.findall()` requires a string.

Comment: Moreover, you're specifying a list instead of a string.

Comment: @devnull indentation is not a problem here: the file is read and then closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re.findall` expects a string as its second argument, but the [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines) method of a file object returns a list.  Perhaps you meant to use the [`read`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) method instead (which returns a string):

```
with open("text2.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()
```